# how to gen certificate openssl TSLv1

Tags: ssl, https, openssl

im interested in cert v1.0 for my local server, 
how to generate pair of public and **private key for server?**

There is a list of supported algo for tls v1:

> ```
> ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-SHA  TLSv1
> ECDHE-RSA-AES256-SHA    TLSv1
> ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-SHA  TLSv1
> ECDHE-RSA-AES128-SHA    TLSv1
> ECDHE-PSK-AES256-CBC-SHA384 TLSv1
> ECDHE-PSK-AES256-CBC-SHA TLSv1 
> RSA-PSK-AES256-CBC-SHA384 TLSv1
> DHE-PSK-AES256-CBC-SHA384 TLSv1
> PSK-AES256-CBC-SHA384   TLSv1
> ECDHE-PSK-AES128-CBC-SHA TLSv1
> RSA-PSK-AES128-CBC-SHA256 TLSv1
> DHE-PSK-AES128-CBC-SHA256 TLSv1
> PSK-AES128-CBC-SHA256   TLSv1
> ```

How to use make one of it suitable for serv?

Answer (score 0):

Your requirement together with the ciphers make no sense:

- You have a mix of ECDSA, RSA and PSK ciphers, i.e. ciphers which require either an ECC certificate, a RSA certificate or no certificate at all. There is no certificate which covers all of this at the same time.
- A certificate is not depending on the TLS version, i.e. there is no TLSv1 certificate.